# KnockoutJS: Exclude computed observables before passing data to server

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am not sure what is the best way to do this. But in http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html there is a section that says "Determining if a property is a computed observable". I used `isComputed` to check if the property is a computed observable.

I would like to exclude/remove computed observables from `self.formItems()` before passing the values to my server.

Here is part of my code with the AJAX request to send the data back to the server.

```
for (var prop in self.formItems()) {
    // console.log(ko.isComputed(self.formItems()[prop].isRadio)); //true (because this is computed)
    // console.log(ko.isComputed(self.formItems()[prop].field_label)); //false (because this is not a computed element)
    for(var form_prop in self.formItems()[prop]) {
        // console.log(form_prop+': '+ko.isComputed(self.formItems()[prop][form_prop]));
        if(self.formItems()[prop].hasOwnProperty(form_prop) && !ko.isComputed(self.formItems()[prop][form_prop])) {
            // result_no_computed_observables[prop][form_prop] = ko.toJS(self.formItems()[prop][form_prop]);
            console.log(self.formItems()[prop][form_prop]);
        }
        // ko.cleanNode(self.formItems()[prop][form_prop])
    }
}

$.ajax({
    'type': 'POST',
    'url': appUrl+'/editors/saveform/'+memberListId+'.json',
    'cache': false,
    'dataType': 'json',
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'data': ko.toJSON({
        'id': theFormDetails.id(),
        'name': theFormDetails.name(),
        'description': theFormDetails.description(),
        'success_text': theFormDetails.success_text(),
        'success_redirect': theFormDetails.success_redirect(),
        'form_elements': self.formItems()     /* <--- I would like to remove computed observables from this*/
    }),
    'success': function(result) {
        alert('success!!!');
    },
    'statusCode': {
        403: function() {
          alert("Your session has probably expired. Please login again.");
          window.location = appUrl+"/users/login";
        }
    }
});
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked out the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html)?  You can call `ko.mapping.toJS()` to convert a model back to raw JSON, and it lets you control all sorts of behaviors.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I have just tried to `console.log(ko.mapping.toJS(self.formItems()))` - but I do not see how I can solve my problem with this. Sorry.

Comment: Do you have the mapping pluggin loaded?

Comment: Yup, I have loaded it and I can see a JSON object in my console. It has the same properties as `self.formItems()` before the unmapping - including the computed observables.

Comment: Did you pass in the `ignore` configuration property to define which properties you want to exclude?

Comment: Thank you. It is a very quick and clean solution. `var clean_data = ko.mapping.toJS(self.formItems(), { ignore: ['isTextbox','computedA', 'computedB']});` Then I passed `clean_data` - `'form_elements': clean_data`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, I'd recommend using the [mapping plugin](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html) which makes this quite easy.  This is an optional plugin you'll need to download and reference.  This allows you to pass configuration properties into the serialization and deserialization functions to control exactly what fields get serialized and how.  Basically, you'd be able to do something like:

```
var json = ko.mapping.toJS(model, { ignore: ['form_elements'] });
```

To exclude the `form_elements` property from the model.

Another way to do this, without using the plugin, is to override the `toJSON` method.  Something like:

```
viewModel.prototype.toJSON = function() {
    var copy = ko.toJS(this);
    delete copy.form_elements; // Remove form_elements field
    return copy;
};
```

[Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/SvJWf/).